# Reachability ForLocalWiFi

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I have downloaded `Reachability` Class from the [developer's portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). On network change this is not working. Below is my code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

self.wifiReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
[self.wifiReachability startNotifier];
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability:self.wifiReachability];     

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note    
{      
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];      
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);        
    [self updateInterfaceWithReachability:curReach];      
}
```

Above notificaion is not calling on network change. Any suggestions?

Comment: "reachabilityForLocalWiFi" method is removed from new Rechability class. Do you really want to use that method ?

Comment: Yes, i want to use the same library